# Having trouble in replacing fragments in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to replace the fragment & getting these errors

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.icHome.setOnClickListener(){

        replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
        //error- change parameter 'fragment' type of function to 'replaceFragment' to 'HomeFragment'
        Toast.makeText(this, "Home is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    binding.icCategory.setOnClickListener(){
        replaceFragment(CategoryFragment())
        Toast.makeText(this, "Category is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    binding.icSettings.setOnClickListener(){
        replaceFragment(SettingsFragment())
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
private fun replaceFragment(fragment : Fragment){
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentReplace,fragment) //error Create extension function 'FragmentTransaction'
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

}

PS: I am new to the kotlin so sorry for the mistakes.

fragment replace is a FrameLayout. & ic_home & all are the imageView

Tried several codes still can't figure out.

Comment: https://youtu.be/-JwbrsKr9FE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Might not be related but if you use binding then you must set the content view to the bindings root `setContentView(binding.root)`. In your code you are setting the content twice. You should remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

2.For any transaction you should use `setReorderingAllowed(true)` so in your replaceFragment() method you should have :

```
supportFragmentManager.commit {
replace(R.id.fragmentReplace,fragment)
setReorderingAllowed(true)
}
```

3. Do not use frame layout. Your R.id.fragmentReplace should be a FragmentContainerView. See doc https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView

Comment: Thank you @Purple6666 for pointing out the flaws in the code really helpful.